# Python get instruction none

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

how can I do to enter a lista of default when the lista value returned by the get function is none ?

Thank you

```
def GETLISTA():
    iptvset = int(addon.getSetting('iptvset')) + 1
    lista = addon.getSetting('lista' + str(iptvset))
    return lista

lista = GETLISTA()
params = getParams()
url = lista
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [ask]. You need to specify what you mean... do you want to ask for user input? which `get` function? `null` isn't a valid value in Python... perhaps you mean `None`?

Comment: Can you try to elaborate? Sometimes, when we've been looking at our code for a long time trying to figure something out, we forget that other people don't understand the context. Try to give a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) to assign a "default value" to a variable. This works because `a or b` is equivalent to `a if a else b`. Thus you could write

```
lista = GETLISTA() or some_default
```

Notice, however, that this will also use `some_default` if `GETLISTA()` evaluates to an empty list `[]`, or any other "falsy" value, not only if it returns `None`. This may or may not be a problem in your case. Alternatively, use the ternary operator

```
lista = GETLISTA()
lista = some_default if lista is None else lista
```

or a simple `if` check (slightly longer, but IMHO clearer than the ternary):

```
lista = GETLISTA()
if lista is None:
    lista = some_default
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with:                                                                             lista = GETLISTA() or 'http://************************''